# SQL log shipping restore failed and index performance stats, capture stats

Tags: sql-server-2008, log-shipping

Please help me here,

WE have production SQL server 2008 R2 having database MicrosoftDynamicsAX database, on which I have tried to configure log shipping twice. but failed twice,

Upon configuration, The backup job on Primary Runs fine every 15 mins

On secondary, the Copy job, copy log files from primary to secondary share folder,

all share folders have full access permissions

Error at The BACKUP JOB, which will search through the secondary share and SKIPS EACH T-LOG BACKUP, in history details its written, searching through folder , skips each ..trn files, could not find log file that can be applied to database and say backup job successful,

I can see no T-log backup deleted manually/automatically from share folder

After hour or so, the monitor start throwing red alerts, back up job has thresh hold of 45 minutes, and has not performed restore since 137 minutes etc. :crying:

when I inspect the full backup LSN number and that of LSN of  T-log generated upon Log shipping configuration, there is mismatch.

I CHECKED OTHER JOBS RUNNING ON PRODUCTION SERVER, ONLY TWO JOBS RUNNING  "Performance  iNDEX Stats" HOURLY BASIS,  && CAPTURE STATS ON  MicrosoftDynamicsAX database.

Please refer attached Full backup, T-log back generated and other stats jobs running  snaps,

Kindly help me, I am unable to trace the root cause why, Log shipping is fails,

APpricitae your replies

Answer (score 0):

checks to be made:

--SQL server agent running under local and not domain account.
--restore job for this secondary database is enabled and is scheduled to run at the appropriate frequency.
--Also, try copy and restoring manually and see if any particular alerts during restore.
--check if the account has proper access to copy the files from the production to DR server.

Let us know if any other questions.
Regards,
Shai